# Problem software instalation 'Demeter'

Tags: software-installation

I am a novice with Linux (I have elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya 64bit) and I can't solve a problem occurring during the installation of a software suite called 'Demeter' (X-ray spectroscopy data analysis). Even though there is a very detailed and simple guide on the site that explain how to install the software for Ubuntu 12.04 OS, it seems that it does not work for me (code lines not compatible with my OS?).

Guide web address: https://bruceravel.github.io/demeter/documents/SinglePage/demeter_nonroot.html

In the first section 'preparing your machine', for the first command (the 'apt-get install ... ' line) everything seems to go well. But when I want to set-up the local copy of Perl I get this:

```
flibuque@flibuque-X302LA:~$ cd
flibuque@flibuque-X302LA:~$ pwd
/home/flibuque
flibuque@flibuque-X302LA:~$ echo 'eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)' >> ~/.bashrc
flibuque@flibuque-X302LA:~$ source ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/flibuque/.bashrc: line 168: syntax error near unexpected token `$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)'
bash: /home/flibuque/.bashrc: line 168: `esaceval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)'
flibuque@flibuque-X302LA:~$
```

Do you have a idea of what I could do here?

Besides since then every times I open the terminal I have the the line 6) and 7) showing up at the top of the 'flibuque@flibuque-X302LA:'...

Any help is welcome! Thank you!

Sylvain

Answer (score 1):

You should open your ~/.bashrc file with a text editor and correct the last line (line 168) so that there are two separate lines:

```
esac
eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)
```

The problem is that there was no newline at the end of the file so when you appended the line starting with `eval` as suggested it did get mixed up with the last line `esac`.

Comment: If you think that your question has been answered, feel free to accept the answer as well, thanks!